# Ant on a triangle

Tags: probability, solution-verification, markov-chains

A bug jumps around the vertices of a triangle. At every jump, it moves from its current
position to either of the other two vertices with probability 1/2 each (independently of how
it arrived at its current position). The bug starts at vertex 1. Let $p_n$ be the probability
that it is at vertex 1 after n jumps. Find the value of $p_n$ for each n. (Hint: find an
appropriate first-order linear recurrence relation.) What happens to $p_n$ as n → ∞?

I found the recurrence relation $p_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(1-p_n)$ because the bug is at 1 at time $n+1$ if it isn't at 1 at time $n$ and it jumps onto it at time $n+1$, which happens with probability 1/2.

Solving this gave $p_n = -\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n+\frac{1}{3}$.

Can anyone check if they agree with this please?

Comment: If I plug in $n=1$ to your formula I get $-1/3$ instead of $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I just edited it and I think it satisfies the boundary conditions now.

Comment: Looks right to me.